An fmu generated by visual studio runs on simulink, but it encounters an error:"Unable to load dynamic library"
I have a Visual Studio 2013 project, coding by C. And I generate a dll file, and put it into a directory of fmu file structrue, and there are some other sources like modelDescription.xml. I compress the dir into an fmu. And then I import it to simulink2021b by fmu block, it can be recognized as an fmu, and can update(Ctrl+D), but when I run it, it display an error:
"Error in supplied FMU: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\\fmu_test\simulink\slprj\_fmu\e06e7f3203c5e5995bff88ca17b48bde\fmu-minimum65\binaries\win64\BaeSAR_VSP.dll': ************".  

************ is a string of codes that cannot be correctly display.
When I run it on simulink 2017b, the error ************* change into Try to access invalid addresses.
What is the problem with my fmu? How can I generate a correct fmu by VS2013? (Or other VS
version)
The project code is very simple.
I check my fmu by FMUChecker-2.0.4-win64 tool, it output some info and two errors:
[ERROR][FMUCHK] Platform type returned from CS FMU 'win64' does not match the checker 'default'
[ERROR][FMUCHK] FMU logger callback does not propagate component environment to the application`

And the next output is:
[INFO][FMUCHK] Initialized FMU for simulation starting at time 0
0.0000000000000000E+000
2.0000000000000000E+003
4.0000000000000000E+003
....
9.9800000000000000E+005
1.0000000000000000E+006
[INFO][FMUCHK] Simulation finished successfully at time 1e+06
FMU check summary:
FMU reported:
        0 warning(s) and error(s)
Checker reported:
        0 Warning(s) 
        2 Error(s)  

I had copy the dll files that this fmu dependents on into the resources dir, and make sure that they are all 64-bit, but it doesn't work, the simulink error is still Try to access invalid addresses.

Please provide more information how you create your FMUs:
Do you use a template such as the Reference FMUs? There you find a blueprint how to use cmake to create VS-Project  to compile and generate FMUs that work fine: https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#build-the-fmus. In the "releases" you can find working FMUs.
Most probably you have placed the dll in the wong subdirectory.
The development of the FMU Compliance Checker has been discontinued. Please use one of the tools listed on https://fmi-standard.org/validation/ instead.

I use the VS2013 to generate a dll file of my simple C project, and edit an modelDescription.xml, and put the dll file in directory "binaries\win64", and change the zip to a fmu, and then I import it to the simulink. Simulink can recognize it as a fmu. And I also use the fmpy_gui tool, it can also be recognized as an fmu,but could not run.

Can I only use Visual Studio to generate the dll of the fmu?

Can you share the modelDescription.xml and a screenshot of the file structure of the FMU? Have you compared it to working examples of FMUs, e.g. from the Reference FMUs? Please compare your build process with that of the Reference FMUs.

Can I only use Visual Studio to generate the dll of the fmu?
In principle you can use any compiler that is compatible with your code and build process


I can't share a screenshot because the company requires employees to keep their content secret. The file structure of the FMU is as follow:
xxx.fmu/
├── binaries/
│   └── win64/
│       └── xxx.dll  # Windows 64bit
│
├── documentation/
│
├── sources/
│
├── resources/
│   └── ...  #
│
└── modelDescription.xml

A similar issue occurs, if the FMU dll requires another dll which is not included in the FMU, or if the importing tool does not handle the dependent dlls correctly. So, you must make sure that the dependent dlls are available on the executing computer or in the FMU. You can also try to avoid dependencies by linking statically.
You can observe the dependency tree with the dependency walker (https://www.dependencywalker.com) or reimplementations of that tool (https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies).
Visual Studio binaries depend on the runtime libraries (e.g. msvcr*.dll) if you set the switch "/md". If you set the switch "/mt" the dependency is linked statically to your library.

Please use the Reference FMUs and the build process there as a blueprint how to generate well defined FMUs from C-Code.
https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs
